# running a query with date_column = current_date wont finish executing in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

If I run these 2 queries:

```
select *
from public.table_name
where date_column = '2018-03-28'
limit 10

select *
from public.table_name
where date_column = current_date - 2
limit 10
```

The first one will return very quick, the second one would take forever. After checking more, it seems as the first one is scanning the whole table, the second one is properly checking the index. How do I use a dynamic date call that would hit the index properly?

version: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit

Comment: Do you mean the first/fast one is using the index and the second/slow one is doing a seq scan? Can you also post the data type of `date_column`? Finally can you post an `EXPLAIN` of the long-running query? At first glance I can't think of why there should be a difference, but you could also try changing the second one to `date_column = (SELECT current_date - 2)` and see what effect that has.

Comment: 1) what data type is date_column? TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMPTZ or TEXT or what?
2) What does `SELECT current_date - 2` return? It may be that your timezone setting is something other than what you would expect and current_date - 2 might be returning some other date than '2018-03-28' and if there are not 10+ rows with that date in the table, then it might decide not to use the index and just go over the whole table.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** for both queries. If the second query "never finishes", then at least post the output of a simple `explain`. for that one. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)